# Access a function which is defined inside a functional component in navigationOptions

Tags: react-native, state, hook, react-functional-component

I need to access a function which uses state values. Following is a sample code of my current implementation.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { View, Text, Button, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import MaterialCommunityIcons from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons';
import { withNavigationFocus } from 'react-navigation';

const HomeScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
    const [name, setName] = useState('');

    useEffect(() => {
        navigation.setParams({
            onSave
        });
        // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    }, [onSave]);

    const onSave = () => {
        // name value will be used in this function
        console.log(name);
    };

    return (
        <View>
            <Text>{name}</Text>
            <Button title="Change name" onPress={() => setName('John')} />
        </View>
    );
};

HomeScreen.navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
    const onSave = navigation.getParam('onSave', false);
    return {
        title: 'Home',
        headerRight: (
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={onSave}>
                <MaterialCommunityIcons name="content-save" color={'black'} />
            </TouchableOpacity>
        )
    };
};

export default withNavigationFocus(HomeScreen);
```

Even-though I'm able to access the onSave function. I'm not able to get updated 'name' state. I’m aware that we can reset onSave param on state change, but if there many states needs to be accessed inside onSave function what is the best way to handle this situation?

Answer (score 0):

What if you change the useEffect dependency to 'name' variable:

```
useEffect(() => {
    navigation.setParams({
        onSave
    });
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
}, [name]);
```

Does it make a difference?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As I have mentioned in the question, is this the best way to handle it? If we have around 10 state values to be accessed in onSave function we need to set too many values as dependency.

Comment: I see.. What if you remove all dependencies. like this: "useEffect(() => {...});"